# SQL Server conditional join of four tables in a View

Tags: sql-server, windows, join, view, left-join

This one is driving me crazy, and it might not even be possible. I have four tables listed below. For brevity I have removed unimportant columns, indexes, keys, foreign keys, etc.

```
CREATE TABLE Client(
    ClientID uniqueidentifier ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL DEFAULT (newid()),
    ClientName varchar(250) not null
);
GO

CREATE TABLE Instance(
    InstanceID uniqueidentifier ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL DEFAULT (newid()),
    ClientID uniqueidentifier not null, /* FK into Client */
    InstanceName varchar(48) not null
);
GO

CREATE TABLE Object(
    ObjectID uniqueidentifier ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL DEFAULT (newid()),
    ClientID uniqueidentifier not null, /* FK into Client */
    InstanceID uniqueidentifier null,   /* FK into Instance */
    Path varchar(260) not null
);
GO

CREATE TABLE History(
    Timestamp datetime DEFAULT (getdate()),
    ClientID uniqueidentifier null,     /* if not null, references Client */
    InstanceID uniqueidentifier null,   /* if not null, references Instance */
    ObjectID uniqueidentifier null,     /* if not null, references Object */
    Details varchar(1024)
);
GO
```

I am trying to create a view on the History table. The tricky column in the view is **ClientName**. If History.ClientID is not null then it is easy. But if History.ClientID *is* null but ObjectID *is not* null, then it needs to get the ClientName via History.ObjectID->Object.ClientID->Client.ClientName.

This is the best I can come up with, which works if History.ClientID is not null, but I have no idea how to get the ClientName via the ObjectID if History.ClientID is null.  I hope this is all somewhat clear.

```
CREATE VIEW History_Report as
SELECT 
        H.TimeStamp,
        C.ClientName,
        Q.InstanceName,
        O.Path,
        H.Details
from 
    History H
    left join Instance Q ON (H.InstanceID = Q.InstanceID)
    left join Object O on (H.ObjectID = O.ObjectID)
    left join Client C on (H.ClientID = C.ClientID)
GO
```

Is this best done with cursors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW History_Report as
SELECT 
        H.TimeStamp,
        COALESCE(C.ClientName, CO.ClientName) ClientName,
        Q.InstanceName,
        O.Path,
        H.Details
from 
    History H
    left join Instance Q ON (H.InstanceID = Q.InstanceID)
    left join Object O on (H.ObjectID = O.ObjectID)
    left join Client C on (H.ClientID = C.ClientID)
    LEFT JOIN Client CO ON (O.ClientID = CO.ClientID)
GO
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks. I forgot about COALESCE.

Answer (score 1):

The easy approach is to simply add an additional `join` into your query:

```
CREATE VIEW History_Report as
SELECT 
        H.TimeStamp,
        isnull(C.ClientName, CO.ClientName) as ClientName,
        Q.InstanceName,
        O.Path,
        H.Details
from History H
    left join Instance Q
        on(H.InstanceID = Q.InstanceID)
    left join Object O
        on(H.ObjectID = O.ObjectID)
    left join Client C
        on(H.ClientID = C.ClientID)
    left join Client CO
        on(O.ClientID = CO.ClientID
          and H.ClientID is null    -- This will help limit duplicates
          )
GO
```

Though you will need to watch out for duplicates when you add additional `join`s in this way.  Without seeing your data this is not something we can say for sure.